# How to send and execute PHP code from one file to another?

Tags: php

My motive is to create a code editor that can run HTML as well as PHP codes.
The code editor section is in index.php and output.php is embedded in the index file to display the output.

On executing the code of the textarea (code editor), I reload (using jQuery' .load() function), only the embedded output section in index.php.
The HTML codes are executing properly but the PHP code is not working as expected.

I want that when the page loads, the output.php file (or the output section) should be blank.

### Case 1: Cookies

I tried using cookies to store the text area code, which I echoed in the output.php file.
-> HTML codes worked as expected but PHP scripts didn't.

I know the issue here, that while echoing the code in output.php, the statement becomes something like:

```
echo "<?php echo "some text"; ?>";
```

### Case 2: File Handling

Using file handling I wrote the textarea contents in the output.php file.
Here, both the HTML and PHP codes worked properly until,

At the top of index.php, to clear the contents of output.php on page load, I wrote:

```
$txt = fopen($file, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($txt, "");
fclose($txt);
```

The issue here was that after adding the above code, it cleared the contents of the output file each time I pressed the execute button, resulting in a blank output section all the time.

-> The execute button is of type="button", and using jQuery-Ajax, I sent the text area contents to a file which writes it in output.php. I did this to make sure that the page is not reloaded.

### Case 3:

Instead of using the output.php file, I displayed the output on the index page using jQuery/js methods like .text(), .HTML(), document.write
PHP codes did not worked.

**Questions:**

1. How to send and execute PHP scripts from one page to another?
2. Is there any other way of creating an editor that can run both HTML and PHP codes.
3. Under the above Case 2, why does the content clearing code, written at the top of the index page, worked even when the index page was not reloaded.

I hope that was not too complicated to understand.
Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: You could use POST/GET-commands and call URLS (files) with some parameters :)

Comment: It may be worth trying to focus on 1 of your solutions (maybe 2 as it seems to be giving the closest results) and try and resolve that problem.  At the moment there is too much to try and answer (IMHO)

Comment: _“I hope that was not too complicated to understand.”_ - it was. This question needs less verbal explanation, and more code that shows what you are actually doing, IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to achieve the desired results.

I continued with the above mentioned "Case-2".
I created a PHP condition as:

```
if(isset($_POST['clear'])){
    $txt = fopen("../output.php", "w") or die("Unable to generate output file!");
    fwrite($txt, "");
    fclose($txt);
}
```

Then I created a button named "clear" (type="button" and set its styling to display: none), on click of which, using jQuery-Ajax I submitted the form on the file where the above condition was written.

Finally, on page load, I auto clicked the "clear" button.

Thanks, Everyone for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Answer to question 1:

1. The problem with not sending your code is that the input value for writing output.php does not change at the time of writing the file (no value is entered)

solution:

```
<?php
    $txt = fopen($file, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    if ($handle = fopen($file, "r")) {
        $content = fread($handle, filesize($file));  // each caracters is 1 byte
    }
    fwrite($txt, $content);
    fclose($txt);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a misunderstanding of the concept of all involved technologies here.

Your embedded output.php can not receive any input from anywhere outside of this context where you are because it gets rendered when you request the page.

So the question to send from one file to another does not make any sense here.

Do it the following way:

Have your input.html/php with your code editor form (and the js to send the input of this form to a specific url).
When clicking the submit button, an ajax request sends your code to a "render.php" which renders/evaluates the code and returns the result. This result can be properly displayed by your js code wherever you want to display it.

Thats all in general.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are wanting to change the flow of **execution** from one php file to another, instead of just **including** and executing its contents.

As long as nothing has been echoed to the browser, you can use the header function and then exit the current script.

```
header ('Location: output.php');
exit;
```